# Event loop exception null in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

When I select "Option List" from the option type selection drop-down list in Step 4: Agent Parameters, a get an exception: Event Loop Exception null:
[image]

AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.8.4
Build: 8.8.4.202307181708 x64

I have Windows 11 22H2 version

I've tried to clean workspace folder, restart app and system, but did't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a parameter in other ways by just dragging it into your agent type after creating the agent type itself. Switch it to `OptionList` there

(no idea re the NPE, never seen that)